# Pedir dato con prompt() y almacenarlo en mysql con php

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Estoy trabajando un sistema de venta pero cuando un producto tiene un número de serie unico necesito que me muestre un prompt() para escribir el número de serie y luego almacenarlo en una variable php y almacenarlo en mysql.
Este es mi código:

```
 <?php
    if($tProducto == "AS")
    {
        $sprod = "";
        ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                  var serie = window.prompt("Ingrese el Número de Serie del producto");
            </script>   
            <?php
                 $sprod = "<script type='text/javascript'> document.write(serie); </script>";
               include("datos.php");
               $consultaserie = "UPDATE detalle_pedido_venta set DPV_Serie = '$sprod' where DPV_Detalle_Pedido_Venta = '$NIdV'";
               $results = mysqli_query($db,$consultaserie);
```

Esto sucede al momento de ejecutar un submit, pero mo me almace en la bd el valor de la variable php

Comment: menioname por favor si al final ya obtuviste o conseguiste almacenar el valor

Answer (score 1):

Unos comentarios respecto a tu código, van en este orden:

1. No es necesario que especifiques `text/javascript`
2. La instrucción no debería ser `window.prompt`, en cambio solo trata con `prompt()`
3. No veo donde declares para posteriormente utilizar la variable PHP llamada `$NIdV`, requieres que exista pues la estas usando en tu SQL

Al final tu código debería quedar así

```
<?php
    if($tProducto == "AS")
    {
        $sprod = "";
        ?>
            <script>
                  var serie = prompt("Ingrese el Número de Serie del producto");
            </script>   
            <?php
                 $sprod = "<script> document.write(serie) </script>";
               include("datos.php");
               $consultaserie = "UPDATE detalle_pedido_venta set DPV_Serie = '$sprod' where DPV_Detalle_Pedido_Venta = '$NIdV'";
               $results = mysqli_query($db,$consultaserie);
```

**ACTUALIZACIÓN**

Estas usando la extensión mysqli, pero no usas sentencias preparadas lo cual vuelve a tu SQL totalmente inseguro, te coloco el siguiente ejemplo y te explico lo que deberías hacer

```
$consultaserie = $db->prepare("UPDATE detalle_pedido_venta set DPV_Serie = ? where DPV_Detalle_Pedido_Venta = ?");
 $consultaserie->bind_param("ss", $prod, $NIdV);
 $consultaserie->execute();
```

1. En lugar de colocar las variables directamente en el SQL, sustituyelas por marcadores de posición con el signo `?`
2. Por tu código que leí asumo que la variable donde guardas los datos de conexión es db, entonces como puedes ver accedo a el método `prepare()` para la consulta SQL
3. Con bind param le voy a indicar el tipo de dato que le va a llegar de cada uno, si es número es i, si es cadena de texto es s y las tienes que declarar en el mismo orden que las requiere tu SQL, todo esto entre comillas como puedes checar en el ejemplo
4. ahi mismo dentro de bind param solo separados por comas declaras las variables que tienen los valores que vas a ocupar en tu SQL también en el mismo orden que son requeridas
5. Al final accedes al método execute() para que tu consulta sea llevada a cabo